# Subnetting, Switches, and Routers

Tags: networking, router, ip

I am new at this and want to figure out why my configurations are not working. I have two subnets each connected by a level 2 switch. I have changed my subnets to the following: Subnet 1 has 62 hosts and subnet 2 has 7 hosts. Subnet 1 is as follows: Range 1-62, BC 63, Mask 255.255.255.128. Subnet 2 has 7 hosts, Range is from 64-70, with 71 as the BC. Subnet Mask is 255.255.255.248.

I have each computer connected to a switch and the two switches connected to each other. I am trying to demonstrate how two computers on two different subnets cannot talk to each other via a low-level switch. All works fine here; they cannot ping each other. Now comes the interesting part. I put both computers on the same subnet and have them try to ping each other. They still can't communicate with each other. Says host unreachable. However, four packets went through. What am I missing here?

I also want to eventually add a router, so that the subnets can communicate with each other. I would have to have two routers in that case correct, with each router configured with the private settings of the subnet and then link the two routers together?

Comment: You don't really have two subnets because their IP addresses overlap.

Comment: I have changed my subnets to the following: Subnet 1, has 62 hosts and subnet 2 has 7 hosts. Subnet 1 is as follows:   Range 1-62, BC 63 Mask 255.255.255.128.  Subnet 2 has 7 hosts, Range is from 64-70 with 71 as the BC. Subnet Mask is 255.255.255 248

Comment: I tried to clean up your question, but it's still confusing.  You say, "I have two subnets each connected by ***a*** level 2 switch" but "I have … the two switches connected to each other."  Which is it — one switch or two?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Also, a **/29** subnet does not have 7 host addresses; it has 6.  The **.64** is the address of the subnet in its entirety, and so is reserved, just like the **.0** address in subnets that start with a **0** address.

Comment: There are 2 switches, the 2 switches have a jumper between the two. Each computer is connected to each switch. Yes, I know the 64 is the address of the subnet in its entirety. There are cases where you use the subnet ID as an address of a node so I included it in the range.

Comment: You wrote "I have two subnets each connected by a level 2 switch" <<--  oh really? a subnet is layer 3, you wouldn't connect them with something on layer 2!

Answer (score 1):

If you're new at this then don't start with subnet masks other than `255.255.255.0`.  Let subnet 1 be `192.168.0.0` and subnet 2 be `192.168.1.0`.  That should be able to demonstrate what you want.  When you do add a router you'll only need one router.  It will have two interfaces, one on each subnet.  Once you have that working then you can play around with non-standard subnet masks.

Comment: Even when I put both computers on the same subnet for testing purposes, we couldn't ping each other.

Comment: So, for example, you gave computer1 192.168.0.11/255.255.255.0 and computer2 192.168.0.12/255.255.255.0.  You plugged them into the same switch and they couldn't ping each other?  If that's the case then you have a bad switch, NIC or cable.  Make sure all of your hardware is good and try again.

Comment: When I add a router, I am simply using cheap low level wireless routers. I don't think there is any place to add multiple subnets.

Comment: By definition a router will have two or more interfaces that will have IP's on different subnets. If it doesn't then it can't route between the subnets.  What is the brand/model of your router?

Comment: Netgear WGR614 Wireless-G Router. I have WAN settings and LAN settings but I don't see anywhere to accept multiple subnets.

Comment: 'WAN' and 'LAN' are just fancy names for the two interfaces.  You'll need one plugged into each network with an appropriate IP on each one for the subnet it's plugged into.

Comment: I have the router LAN in the same subnet as computer 1, the WAN setting is for my public IP address from my ISP. It is the routing table I am looking for correct to add the additional subnet correct?

Answer (score 0):

Any system that talks via TCP/IP over Ethernet has to use ARP or other neighbor discovery protocol to find out which MAC belongs to an IP.

Most systems, including Windows, Linux and all common ones, will issue an ARP request the first time they encounter an IP, and then cache the lookup once the other system responds.

I'm betting you probably changed the IP of one system, but the other system is still using a stale ARP entry.  Changing an IP ought to clear the ARP cache, but if you didn't also change the IP on the other system, then it may be sending to the wrong MAC address.  This is corrected by running `arp -d` on the other system to clear the ARP cache.

The four packets that got through are probably ARP requests from the one system.

Comment: I never thought of that. I will clear out the ARP cache tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The daisy chain wasn't working because the cable was a straight through cable instead of a crossover cable. Also, had one faulty switch. I'm still wondering if it is possible to have two subnets on a Netgear wireless router. If so, where do I put the second subnet in the private settings? I simply don't see this anywhere. This is a NetGear WGR614v10

Answer (score -1):

> I put both computers on the same subnet
>   and have them try to ping each other. 
>   They still can't communicate with each other.  Says host unreachable.

If you're saying that you established *physical* connectivity
between the two computers —
i.e., you put them *physically* on the same LAN segment —
while leaving them configured with IP addresses and netmasks
that say that they are on different subnets,
then this is the expected behavior. 
The following is a simplified description of the logic that the IP stack uses
when sending an IP packet:

> Check whether the destination address is on the same subnet
>   as one of the network interfaces (NICs) on this computer.
>
> - If yes, then send the packet directly to the destination
>     using the appropriate interface.
>     (I'm deliberately leaving out a lot of detail here;
>     specifically, regarding ARP.)
> - If no, check whether I know of a router that handles the destination.
>
>   - If yes, send the packet to that router.
>   - If no, check whether I have a default router.
>
>     - If yes, send the packet to the default router.
>     - If no, report "Host unreachable."

I.e., it is possible to have computers on the same *physical* network segment (with *physical* connectivity) that cannot talk to each other,
because they are *logically* on different subnets. 
And it is possible to establish communication between them by adding a router
that routes between the logical subnets —
even though they are on the same physical network. 
(In fact, I have done this.)

> However, four packets went through.
>   When the ping goes out, it says host unreachable,
>   but states 4 packets sent, 4 packets received, no packets lost. 
>   This is the message that has me very confused.

OK, this sounds puzzling. 
I'm still not sure I understand what you've done, so I'll guess:
You have a router. 
Is your test bed connected to the Internet? 
If it is, you probably have a router provided by your ISP.  Your computers
are probably configured to use the ISP's router as their default router. 
So, following the algorithm described above,
your computers send the ping packets to the default router. 
I'll also guess that you *haven't* "told" your router
about your experimental network configuration; so,
when the router gets a packet addressed to the other computer in your home,
it's confused — it doesn't know what to do with it. 
And so it responds with a "Host unreachable" control message
(which is a single ICMP packet).

So — bottom line — your computer has sent four packets (to the router)
and received four "Host unreachable" packets (from the router).

P.S.  No, there's no reason to have two routers for a simple setup like this.

Comment: The purpose of doing this is two fold:  show that placing two computers on different subnets with only a level 2 switch between

Comment: The purpose of doing this is two fold:  First is to show that placing two computers on different subnets with only a level 2 switch between them will not allow communication between the two subnets. Second is to show that if you put both computers on the same subnets, so the Ethernet address were changed to reflect this as well as the subnet mask, that they could ping each other. All of this is done with a level 2 switch. Machine 1 address is now 192.168.0.9 and machine 2 is 192.168.0.10, both with subnet masks of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: When the ping goes out, it says host unreachable, but states 4 packets sent, 4 packets received, no packets lost. This is message that has me very confused. My question with the routers is if I have two different subnets, with two different subnetmasks, won't I have to pick one LAN setting only? Perhaps I am simply not seeing this on the router.